# Reduce JSON-size by turning booleans into an array a good idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, performance, indexof

Beginner here.
I get the following back from my API call:

```
"formatting": {
  "isBold": false,
  "isItalic": false,
  "isUnderlined": false,
  "isFirstWordOfSentence": false
  ... and so on.
},
```

Now it seems quite expensive to send down so much data. We might have a scenario where only 1 item out of 10 is actually set to true, but we would still need to send down all 10 items. I was wondering whether I could structure this in a different way, that saves sending down so much data, but still holds the same amount of information.

I was thinking of storing the data in array like so:

```
"formatting": ['isBold', 'isFirstWordofSentence']
```

and then on the frontend, instead of checking whether `isBold` is `true` I would just do a `formatting.indexOf('isBold') !== -1`. I understand that a disadvantage is that now the code is not so clear anymore, but I would like to know whether it might be viable?

It would definitely reduce the size of my JSONs. At the same time I am not sure whether the `indexOf` calls in the front-end would end up being way more expensive than a simple boolean check? In that case I could always normalize after I fetch though.

Any suggestions or advice would be highly appreciated. Please remember that I am a beginner.

Comment: For clarity you can use `formatting.includes('isBold')`

Comment: What are your performance requirements? Calls/sec, bandwidth, latency, etc. The answer to the question depends on where you think your issue will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider avoiding false values in the API response

```
"formatting": {
  "isUnderlined": true,
  "isItalic": false
}

"formatting": {
  "isUnderlined": true
}
```

conditional search on both the scenarios return the same

If you do end up converting the response to array,
`formatting.indexOf('isUnderlined')` and `formatting.includes('isUnderlined')` returns true if present in array

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which returns a boolean result.

```
formatting.includes('isBold')
```

An even shorter approach is to store only `true` values. This allows to use the property directly without iterating an array.

```
formatting: {
    isBold: true
}
```

The access is the same as for properties with `false`, but the access returns either `true` or `undefined`. In the later case, you could convert to boolean if necessary.

Otherwise take the advantage of Javascript's automatic coercion to a boolean value by using [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)/[*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values in `if` statements or other depending checks, like with a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

As with any question of data sending/parsing, there are many things to consider here.

My inclination is to not make the kind of optimization you're considering here, unless you're dealing with an enormous amount of data [millions/billions of rows simultaneously].

You also don't need to run `!== -1` on `.indexOf()`. Simply checking the truthfulness works. Another user also mentioned that JS arrays have `.includes()`. That being said, this would run a sequential scan of the list, and dictionary lookups are faster. This will certainly slow down whatever is processing the data more than it speeds up sending the data.

Comment: thanks a lot for this. you still think that it wouldn't be worth it if I fetched it like described and then on the front-end straightaway normalized it into the first format? Then I'd only go through the array once and after that would work with dictionary lookups. Or still sounds like I'm doing more harm than good?

Comment: I do appreciate the creative thinking here, but the majority of the delay of the API call is going to be attributed to latency, not necessarily the server building the JSON or the client parsing the JSON.

If you're taking in the array and recreating JSON, I'd not make this optimization. If you add new fields, you then have to change them twice in code.

Answer (score 0):

foreword: for most cases JSON size is irrelevant in terms of cost. if you are looking to reduce latency look into websockets.

answer: to reduce your size you may use some assumptions: if the value is not found, assume it to be false.

sending a JSON of

```
{
  formatting: ['isBold', 'isItalic']
}
```

would be equivalent to

```
{
  formatting: {
    isBold: true,
    isItalic: true,
    isUnderlined: false,
    isFirstWordOfSentence: false
  }
}
```

which then, you may check the value using `Array.prototype.includes`

```
const isBoldTrue = data.formatting.includes('isBold')
```